# Messages DO NOT appear in the Spring Integration (Kafka) ErrorChannel when Broker is unavailable

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-integration

I am working with a simple **Kafka** based project using **Spring Integration** and we require that when the Broker is down, messages will pass into the **ErrorChannel** and we can deal with them /save as 'dead-letters' etc.

What we are getting is a countless run of Exceptions:

```
2017-09-19 17:14:19.651 DEBUG 12171 --- [ad | producer-1] o.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector   : Connection with localhost/127.0.0.1 disconnected

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
```

But the error channel is ***not*** referenced :-/

I have tried to hook it up, but to no avail - here is *part* of my app-context:

```
<bean id="channelExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="1"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10"/>
    <property name="queueCapacity" value="1000"/>
</bean>

<int:channel id="producingChannel" >
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="channelExecutor" />
</int:channel>

<int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter id="kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter"
                                    kafka-template="kafkaTemplate"
                                    auto-startup="true"
                                    channel="producingChannel"
                                    topic="${kafka.topic}">
</int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter>

<int:service-activator input-channel="errorChannel" ref="errorLogger" method="logError" />
<bean id="errorLogger" class="uk.co.sainsburys.integration.service.ErrorLogger" />

<bean id="kafkaTemplate" class="org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="producerConfigs"/> <!-- producerConfigs piece is NOT included! -->
</bean>
```

Sadly, I am *not* an expert at Spring Integration - any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is correct so far. The problem that you are missing the fact of `async` behavior by default in the `KafkaProducerMessageHandler`:

```
/**
 * A {@code boolean} indicating if the {@link KafkaProducerMessageHandler}
 * should wait for the send operation results or not. Defaults to {@code false}.
 * In {@code sync} mode a downstream send operation exception will be re-thrown.
 * @param sync the send mode; async by default.
 * @since 2.0.1
 */
public void setSync(boolean sync) {
```

So, consider to use `sync="true"` attribute on the `<int-kafka:outbound-channel-adapter>`.

In addition, with the latest upcoming versions we have introduced:

```
  <xsd:attribute name="send-failure-channel" type="xsd:string">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation><![CDATA[
                    Specifies the channel to which an ErrorMessage for a failed send will be sent.
                ]]></xsd:documentation>
                <xsd:appinfo>
                    <tool:annotation kind="ref">
                        <tool:expected-type type="org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel" />
                    </tool:annotation>
                </xsd:appinfo>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:attribute>
```

which is useful for the `async` behavior to catch those errors.

Comment: The async failure channel is also avaolable6in 2.1.2 but not with XML configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answers Artem & Gary. So as we are currently using version 2.1.0.RELEASE, we will need to reference `KafkaProducerMessageHandler` and set sync to `true`? This will result in the `java.net.ConnectException` being **thrown** and catchable. So, with this approach, the ErrorChannel is not part of the equation at all?

Comment: Well, I'd suggest to use `<int:outbound-channel-adapter>` with the `KafkaProducerMessageHandler` as a nested bean and all appropriate configuration there, including `sync = true`. Since you use `ExecutoChannel` the `errorChannel` definitely plays its role. Yes, exception is caught and sent to the `errorChannel` as a `payload` of the `ErrorMessage` via `MessagePublishingErrorHandler`