# Payload of the ErrorMessage in ErrorChannel does not contain Kafka Topic

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-integration

Following on from *this* question [Messages DO NOT appear in the Spring Integration (Kafka) ErrorChannel when Broker is unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46305568/messages-do-not-appear-in-the-spring-integration-kafka-errorchannel-when-broke)

I now have it working nicely and the spring integration Kafka *default* **ErrorChannel** is being called when there is an error state, with the associated ErrorMessage. My problem now, is that I need to determine the **Topic** of the message and there is no way to do this, other than including it in the **Message Header**.

What is the best approach for doing this - shall I create a *special* errorChannel that is associated with *one and only one* Topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `payload.failedMessage` property of the error message is the original message that arrived at the adapter.

You could use a `<header-enricher />` upstream of the adapter, to set header `kafka_topic` to the topic. That is the default mechanism used if no `topic` or `topic-expression` is configured on the adapter.